# Unable to bind json data to a table using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, xml

[image: This is My result in console log][image: JSon data]Hi i am Trying to Bind JSON object Data to a table.my issue is i am able to bind entire json object {{metric}} but failed to load each atttribute of json object i.e.,{{metric.EmpId}}.
finally from my observation i found when the converted json object is directly asigned to

$scope.Employees="Employee": [
                              {"EmpId": "4",
                                  "Name": "Chris",
                                  "Sex": "Male",
                                  "Phone": [
                                    {
                                        "_Type": "Home",
                                        "__text": "564-555-0122"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "_Type": "Work",
                                        "__text": "442-555-0154"
                                    }
                                  ],
                                  "Address": {
                                      "Street": "124 Kutbay",
                                      "City": "Montara",
                                      "State": "CA",
                                      "Zip": "94037",
                                      "Country": "USA"
                                  }
                              }
                            ]
                        }

the output is working as i expected but when i assign the direct result

i.e,$scope.Employees=response;it is not working what might be the issue

```js
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="xml2json.js"></script>
     <script>
                var app = angular.module('httpApp', []);
                app.controller('httpController', function ($scope, $http) {
                    $http.get("File1.xml",
                            {
                                transformResponse: function (cnv) {
                                    var x2js = new X2JS();
                                    var aftCnv = x2js.xml_str2json(cnv);
                                    return aftCnv;
                                }
                            })
                    .success(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        $scope.Employees = response;
                        console.log($scope.Employees);
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

```html
 <div>
            <div ng-app="httpApp" ng-controller="httpController">
                <div ng-repeat="metric in Employees">

                    {{ metric}}
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <table>
                        <tr ng-repeat="metric in Employees">
                            {{metric}}
                             <td ng-repeat="cell in metric">{{cell}}</td>
                            <td>{{cell.EmpId}}</td>
                            <td>{{metric.Name}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: can you show the json itself?

Comment: what does your employees response look like ?

Comment: are you getting data in console.log?

Comment: please provide the json object structure.

Comment: Can you please show us the JSON

Comment: {"Employee":[{"EmpId":"1","Name":"Sam","Sex":"Male","Phone":[{"_Type":"Home","__text":"423-555-0124"},{"_Type":"Work","__text":"424-555-0545"}],"Address":{"Street":"7A Cox Street","City":"Acampo","State":"CA","Zip":"95220","Country":"USA"}},{"EmpId":"4","Name":"Chris","Sex":"Male","Phone":[{"_Type":"Home","__text":"564-555-0122"},{"_Type":"Work","__text":"442-555-0154"}],"Address":{"Street":"124 Kutbay","City":"Montara","State":"CA","Zip":"94037","Country":"USA"}}]}

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `json` has the following format:

```
$scope.Employees = {
    "Employee": [
        {
            "EmpId": 1,
            "Name": "Sam"
        },
        {
            "EmpId": 2,
            "Name": "Lucy"
        }
    ]
};
```

You probably would want to do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="employeeList in Employees">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="employee in employeeList">
             <td>{{employee.EmpId}}</td>
             <td>{{employee.Name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried the same its not working.actualy my xml data is converting in to json which looks like above image entire json object can be retrive but the particular details cannot that is EmpId,Name etc

Comment: Is your json a string?

Comment: I checked your json on `jsoneditoronline.org` and it had some unknown extra characters. I got it working on my machine after removing those.

Comment: just checked with my json on jsoneditoronline.org and its working good there is no problem with json object .There is some thing going wroing at ng-repeat and my JSon is an Object

Comment: Thanks for u r continues supportCheck the jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/a5khgLeL/2/ when i put json object its working good but where the error."The is no problem with json object i hope"

Comment: Hii Just observed some thing when i put json object with in aspx $scope.Employees = {
                            "Employee": [
                              {
                                  "EmpId": "1",
                                  "Name": "Sam",
                                  "Sex": "Male",
                                  "Phone": [
                                     it is working fine were as $scope.Employees=resoponse its not working

Comment: Need to look at what `xml_str2json()` does.

Comment: it is converting Xml file to json.there is also no problem with conversion to json  the same converted json object when i directly assigned to "$scope.Employees" its working.but what happen when i put the response

Comment: It should be `response.data` instead of just `response`. For more info: [$http documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: ya prashkr even checked but it is not useful